# Disable background video when popup opens

Tags: javascript, html, css, video, background

I have this video background with music and I want it to mute or disable when a video popup opens as it also has music.

**HTML Background:**

```
<section class="waypoint video-block fullscreen" data-hash="welcome" style="padding:0;">
    <video autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" poster="img/VideoHDimg.png" class="background-video">
        <source type="video/mp4" src="video/VideoHD.mp4">
        <source type="video/ogm" src="video/family_1.ogm">
    </video>
```

**HTML Popop:**

```
<div id="video-popup" class="mfp-hide self-video-popup"><div class="some-element">
    <video muted="muted" loop="loop" controls poster="img/popupvideo.jpg">
        <source type="video/mp4" src="video/popupvideo.mp4">
        <source type="video/ogm" src="video/family_1.ogm">
    </video>
```

**CSS:**

```
.alt-bg {
    box-sizing: content-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-top: 40px;
    border-color: #E4E4E4;
    padding: 30px 0;
}

.video-block {
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    float:none;
    text-align:center;
    margin:0;
}

.mfp-inline-holder .mfp-content {
    line-height: 0;
    max-width: 900px;
    width: 100%;
}

.self-video-popup {
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-top: 56.25%;
    width: 100%;
}

.self-video-popup .some-element {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 black;
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

.self-video-popup .some-element video {
    width:100%; 
    height:100%;
}

.text-inner {
    position:relative; 
    z-index:4;
}
.background-video {
    width:100%;
    height:760px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
```

JS

```
var MPopup = {
    init: function () {
        MPopup.video('a.play.video');
        MPopup.self_hosted_video('a.play.video.self-hosted');
        MPopup.image('.portfolioContainer');
    },
    video: function (idName) {
        jQuery(idName).magnificPopup({
            mainClass: 'mfp-fade',
            items: {
                src: jQuery(idName).attr('href')
            },
            iframe: {
                markup: '<div class="mfp-iframe-scaler">' +
                        '<iframe class="mfp-iframe" frameborder="0"           allowfullscreen></iframe>' +
                        '<div class="mfp-close"></div>' +
                        '</div>', // HTML markup of popup, `mfp-close` will be replaced by the close button
            },
            type: 'iframe'
        });
    },
    self_hosted_video: function (idName) {
        jQuery(idName).magnificPopup({
            mainClass: 'mfp-fade',
            type: 'inline'
        });
    },
    image: function (idName) {
        jQuery(idName).magnificPopup({
            mainClass: 'mfp-fade',
            delegate: 'article:not(".ajaxed") a:visible',
            gallery: {
                enabled: true,
                navigateByImgClick: true,
                preload: [0, 1] // Will preload 0 - before current, and 1 after the current image
            },
            callbacks: {
                buildControls: function () {
                    if (jQuery.magnificPopup.instance.items.length > 1)
                        this.contentContainer.append(this.arrowLeft.add(this.arrowRight));
                },
                open: function () {
                    jQuery('.mfp-description').append(this.currItem.el.data('title'));
                },
                change: function () {
                    var mfp = jQuery.magnificPopup.instance;
                    var container = jQuery(mfp.container);

                    if (mfp.index >= mfp.items.length - 1)
                        container.addClass('mfp-last');
                    else
                        container.removeClass('mfp-last');
                    if (mfp.index == 0)
                        container.addClass('mfp-first');
                    else
                        container.removeClass('mfp-first');
                },
                afterChange: function () {
                    jQuery('.mfp-description').empty().append(this.currItem.el.data('title'));
                }
            },
            image: {
                verticalFit: true,
                markup: '<div class="mfp-figure   mfp-with-anim">' +
                        '<div class="mfp-img"></div>' +
                        '<div class="mfp-bottom-bar">' +
                        '<div class="mfp-description"></div>' +
                        '<div class="mfp-close"></div>' +
                        '</div>' +
                        '</div>'
            },
            type: 'image',
            closeOnContentClick: false,
            midClick: true,
        });

    }
}
```

I want the background video to mute or to stop playing when the video popup opens and comes to normal when video popup close.

Comment: where is your JS code? have you tried anything? all you need to do in the js is in the popup function of the JS `var mediaElement = document.querySelector(".background-video");
mediaElement.pause();`

Comment: This is completely stopping the background video from playing when the web page loads, I want it to stop when the popup opens. I have tried other methods but they are just stopping the scroll not the background video.

Comment: read what I wrote again.. put this code when the popup opens..

Comment: It is important to include the right code in your question so people are able to help you. And then I don't mean irrelevant CSS and a complete copy of some minified JS library.

Comment: I included the correct JS now, still haven't figured it out how to pause the video, please help.